# drawing the black canvas on my screen is not working, no black rectangle gets drawn

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I am trying to draw a blank black rectangle to the screen for my canvas so I can begin making my pong game but I do not see anything?

I have checked to see if I am getting any errors but I am not

```
html: 
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<title>jatt the maquebla</title>
<meta name="description" content="The HTML5 Herald">
<meta name="author" content="SitePoint">



</head>

<body>
<canvas id="pong" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
<script src="App.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

javascript :

```
// select the canvas that we have made in our html file
const cvs = document.getElementById("pong");
const ctx = cvs.getContext("2d");

// draw our rectangle function 

function drawRect(x, y, w, h, color) {
ctx.fillStyle = color;
ctx.fillRect(x,y,w,h);
}

drawRect(0, 0, cvs.wdith, cvs.height, "BLACK");
```

Comment: Is the provided javascript saved in a file named `App.js` that lives on the same level as the html document?

Comment: yes, it is, and they are both saved in the same folder. I have also tried opening the file in chrome and firefox to see if it may be a browser issue.

Comment: When I try this (fixing `cvs.wdith` to say the proper `cvs.width`) it works fine for me?